# If contains characters then x, else y (Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have this code which should work in theory, but it doesn't.

I guess there is something that it's missing:

```
function containsWords(words, word) {
    return words.filter(w => w === word).length > 0;
}

async function grabResult(page) {
    const message = await page.$eval(
        'div > div:nth-child(2)',
        (el) => el.innerText
    );
    
    const username = await page.$eval(
        'child(15) .username',
        (el) => el.innerText
    );

    return {
        message: containsWords(['http', 'https'], message) ? '' : message,
        username: username
    };
};


module.exports = grabResult;
```

Basically, if there's "http" or "https" in the message, the above code should output an empty message:

```
{ message: '', username: 'John' }
```

If none of these words are detected, then it should output the message normally:

```
{ message: 'message text', username: 'John' }
```

However, right now even if the message does contain "http" and "https", it still returns the message with those words.

So it either doesn't detect these words, or simply doesn't execute containsWords filter at all.

It simply ignores and outputs every message, regardless of my chosen stop words.

I would appreciate if someone knowledgable would look into the code and tell me what I'm missing here.

thanks.

Comment: It seems you're looking for [Check if an array of strings contains a substring in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440317/check-if-an-array-of-strings-contains-a-substring-in-javascript). Note how the other question boiled the problem down to a simple, reproducible scenario with sample input that made it easy to tell what they needed. I was able to find this post with the search "javascript check if a substring is in any element of an array of strings". Again -- no Puppeteer.

Comment: got it working. Thanks for your time and effort in trying to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `containsWords()` you compare the entire message with each word. To check if the message contains any word, you need something like this:

```js
function containsWords(words, message) {
    return words.some(w => message.includes(w));
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked like a charm! Thanks a ton! Lol it's you again :) thanks man for your help, appreciate it. You have helped me with puppeteer in the past :)

Comment: @robert0 Glad it helped. Happy coding)